# Nothing in my GUI is showing up except for the buttons?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a GUI that looks like this:

JLabel and JTextField side by side at the top,
array of JLabels in the center,
two buttons side by side at the bottom

However, only the buttons at the bottom show up and the center and north regions of the BorderLayout are completely blank. I've looked around at similar problems but most of them seem to be that they forgot to add the component to the panel, which isn't the case for me. Could someone help me out?

```
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  public class Driver11
  {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("Unit4, Lab11: Decimal to Binary");
     frame.setLocation(100, 50);
     frame.setSize(400, 150);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.getContentPane().add(new Panel11());
     frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

 public class Panel11 extends JPanel
 {
  private JTextField box;
  private JLabel label;
  private Display11 display;
  private JButton button2;
   public Panel11()
  {
     setLayout(new BorderLayout());

     JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
     panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));   
     add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 

     label = new JLabel("Enter an integer from 0 to 255: ");
     label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 5)); 
     label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT); 
     panel.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST); 

     box = new JTextField("", 5); 
     box.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
     panel.add(box, BorderLayout.EAST); 

     display = new Display11();
     add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

     JPanel south = new JPanel();
     south.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     JButton button1 = new JButton("Convert");
     button1.addActionListener(new Listener1());
     south.add(button1);
     button2 = new JButton("Step");
     button2.addActionListener(new Listener2());
     south.add(button2);
     button2.setEnabled(false);
     label = new JLabel("");
     south.add(label);
  }
```

Comment: What is Display11 ??

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa it's just a display object that I used as a placeholder for the center

Comment: I run your code with using a JPanel instead of Display11 and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correctly place according to the layouts: BorderLayout is only for the global Panel -  the other things have different layouts (as you make them) so should not use NORTH/WEST/EAST indiscriminately wherever. Just for where it applies.

```
 public Panel11()
{
 setLayout(new BorderLayout());

 JPanel panel = new JPanel(); 
 panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));   
 add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 

 label = new JLabel("Enter an integer from 0 to 255: ");
 label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 5)); 
 label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT); 
 panel.add(label);

 box = new JTextField("", 5); 
 box.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
 panel.add(box); 

 display = new Display11();
 add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER); 

 JPanel south = new JPanel();
 south.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
 JButton button1 = new JButton("Convert");
 button1.addActionListener(new Listener1());
 south.add(button1);
 button2 = new JButton("Step");
 button2.addActionListener(new Listener2());
 south.add(button2);
 button2.setEnabled(false);
 label = new JLabel("");
 south.add(label);
 add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```